# Uso de std::less con std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Estoy intentando *meter* `std::function< >` en un `std::set< >`. Para ello, hace falta una función que compare los valores introducidos.

Como `std::function` no proporciona ningún operador de comparación, he pensado en esto:

```
#include <functional>

template< typename... ARGS > class Test {
  using function_type = std::function< void( ARGS... ) >;
  using target_type = void ( * )( ARGS... );

  static inline bool less( const function_type &f1, const function_type &f2 ) noexcept {
    std::less< target_type > l;
    return l( f1.target< target_type >( ), f2.target< target_type >( ) );
  }
};

Test< int, int > test;
```

Al intentar compilar

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c test.cpp

Obtengo una *bonita* lista de errores:

> In static member function `less( ... )`:
>   error: expected primary-expresion before `>`
>   error: expected primary-expresion before `)`
>   error: expected primary-expresion before `>`
>   error: expected primary-expresion before `)`

<sub>Nota: El código es el mínimo reproducible. He mantenido lo que creo que es importante</sub>

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El analizador sintáctico se hace un lío al interpretar la función plantilla de un objeto cuyo tipo depende de parametros plantilla, para desambiguar la interpretación del analizador se necesita añadir la palabra clave `template`:

```
template< typename... ARGS > class Test {
  using function_type = std::function< void( ARGS... ) >;
  using target_type = void ( * )( ARGS... );

  static inline bool less( const function_type &f1, const function_type &f2 ) noexcept {
    std::less< target_type > l;
    return l( f1.template target< target_type >( ), f2.template target< target_type >( ) );
//               ~~~~~~~~   son funciones plantilla!   ~~~~~~~~
  }
};
```

Sin añadir `template` el analizador lo interpreta de otra manera:

```
//            v <-- Menor que
l( (f1.target < target_type) >( ), 
//  ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~
//   simbolo      simbolo
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- expresión.
```

El analizador encuentra una expresión (no la evalúa es un analizador sintáctico) y sigue interpretando el texto, viendo que tras una expresión "*esto menor que aquello*" siendo uno de los operandos un tipo (`target_type`) de manera que la expresión no es válida y emite el error que hemos visto.

Comment: ¡¡ Si señor !! Es la primera vez que me encuentro con esto O_O

Comment: @Trauma es que siempre andas probando cosas raras... :P. Muy buena explicación.